# How to solve failure in plugging external DVD driver in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, devices, automounting, dvd

I have bought an [external DVD driver](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07QG9JN79/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) but, after plugging (or booting with the unit already plugged) I see the unit listed in the resources of the computer but I cannot access it:

[image]

If I try to access the driver via VLC, I get the error `VLC is unable to open the MRL 'cdda:///dev/sr0'`.

The content of fstab is:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=341faa1b-4e49-49d7-85a4-e33acecb2212 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=24D6-7429  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

What is the right way to plug a DVD in Ubuntu 20.04? Is it a problem with the driver (I need to buy another brand more Linux-prone)? Or do I need to change the permission of the driver with some `sudo` commands?

After I plug the DVD driver I get:

```
$ ls -lt | less | grep sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           3 May 27 21:15 cdrom -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           3 May 27 21:15 cdrw -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           3 May 27 21:15 dvd -> sr0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           3 May 27 21:15 dvdrw -> sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root   cdrom    11,   0 May 27 21:15 sr0
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there a disk in the drive? Have you tried putting one in? Does `eject` work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your drive hasn't been mounted. Please follow the steps below:

1. Fire up a terminal and type `mkdir /media/cdrom`.
2. Then, type `sudo mount -t auto /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom`.
3. See if it works; if not, reboot and check if you can access it.

This *should* work. If not, please leave a comment.

EDIT: please try the steps below.

1. Open up a terminal and write `cd /dev/`.
2. Then, `ls -lt | less` and see if you find `dvd -> sr0` or `cdrom -> sr0`.

Comment: Thank you, I got the following:
```
$ sudo mkdir /media/cdrom
$ sudo mount -t auto /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
mount: /media/cdrom: special device /dev/cdrom does not exist.
# mounted devide
$ sudo mount -t auto /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
mount: /media/cdrom: /dev/sr0 is not a valid block device.
```
Then same thing: device first detected (the folder of the drive was empty) then removed.

Comment: Thank you. Please make a backup of your existing `/etc/fstab` to a location of your choice and then edit the non-backup by adding `/dev/sr0 /media/ udf,iso9660 noauto,user,ro 0 0`. Save and reboot.

Comment: Thanks but the problem persists. Would running a DVD need sr0 or something else? could be a brand problem? Perhaps some brands work out of the box...

Comment: I updated the question, sr0 is shown in /dev/ but the driver does not come up in X11